# Error using highcharts to create heatmap with csv file

Tags: csv, highcharts, heatmap

I'm using Highcharts to create a heatmap based on a csv file. It doesn't work somehow.It returns a blank chart. I've described the csv file and htm coding in the follow. Appreciate any help to get it work.

csv file looks like this:

```
Tranche 1y 2y 3y
CDX24 100 200 300
CDX25 200 100 50
```

The htm coding for generating heatmap:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>CVA Credit Exposure</title>


        <!-- 1. Add these JavaScript inclusions in the head of your page -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

        <!-- 2. Add the JavaScript to initialize the chart on document ready -->
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var chart;
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $.get('CS01terms.csv', function(csv) {
                $('#CS01').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'heatmap',
                    marginTop: 40,
                    marginBottom: 80,
                    plotBorderWidth: 1
                    },
                    data: {
                        csv: csv
                    },
                title: {
                    text: 'CS01 exposure',
                    align: 'left'
                },

                colorAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    minColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    maxColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                },
                legend: {
                    align: 'right',
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    margin: 0,
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    y: 25,
                    symbolHeight: 280
                },

                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] + '</b> sold <br><b>' +
                    this.point.value + '</b> items on <br><b>' + this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
                    }
                }

                });
                });
            });




        </script>

    </head>
    <body>


        <!-- 3. Add the container -->
        <Table width="100%" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=0>
        <tr>
        <td> <div id="CS01" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div> </td>

        </tr>   
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Have you looked in the console?

Comment: Firstly remove data.js , not needed there

Comment: Do you use webserver or load file from local file system ? Please run [the console](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console) and let us know what kind of errors do you have.

Comment: @SebastianBochan I load file from local file system. When I open the html as webpage, it has a blank heatmap chart.

Comment: @SebastianBochan The codes are saved here (I don't know how to upload the csv file, but the csv file content and format is like I described above in my question): http://jsfiddle.net/b34njaff/

Comment: To load CSV you need to use webserver, because get file from local file system is blocked by browsers.

Comment: @SebastianBochan I don't know how to do that, and spend a week figuring this out but no examples of "highcharts heatmap with external csv file" available online. I will be much appreciate it if you can just go over my script or provide an easy example...thx

Comment: But you cannot load file or parse data, because Im confused.